# In Which NGINX Configuration File in Centos 7, I Can Add Location try_files Command To Resolve Permalink 404 Error

Tags: nginx, centos7, permalinks, conf.d

I am using Centos 7 and Webuzo Panel, For resolving pretty permalink 404 error issue on
NGINX server. I added at the bottom of file the below location try_files command

**location / {**

**index index.php index.html index.htm;**

**try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;**

**}**

in File Name : **common** (which is available in **/usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d**)

2 Days Back, When I did this, this resolved the permalinks issue in NGINX but every midnight 12 o'clock this 'common' file gets reset and my **added text** goes disappear and again my sites start facing permalinks issue (only home page works fine) and again I have to add the same try_files command in that file. I have tried adding the above text in nginx.conf but it shows invalid when I restart nginx.

My setup has combined single nginx config file for all the available sites on server.

[conf.d folder screenshot showing list of config.files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qThvs.png)

Please guide me in which nginx configuration file, I can add command for *location* for permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to `/usr/loca/apps/nginx/nginx.conf`